# How could I achieve the same navigation using CSS3? (currently flash AS3)

Tags: flash, drupal, css, navigation

Link to my actual flash demo: http://nside-elite.techiedesign.net/redbox/flashtest.html

I created this navigation using Adobe Flash (AS3 script) which works quite well. The problem is that I'm using Drupal for my website's CMS. Trying to implement this flash navigation using Drupal would be a big chore in itself right there. But even then, it would be hard for it to be flexible enough so that I could change the links as needed through Drupal's Primary Links.

One of the last flaws with using a flash-based navigation (even assuming I could get it to work) is that spiders and bots may not index the site correctly if my code uses a great deal of hacks in order to visually have it working.

Now, I can do my own research and coding with CSS as I am very firmilliar with CSS 2.1 and learning basic CSS3 currently. One of the problems I see though is the effect I'm using on mouse hover. I can't see how I could get the metal tab to drop down upon mouse over, and also have the light above it fade in at the same time. The reason why I see this is a problem is because the clickable (or 'hover area') area on the light isn't directly on top of the actual image, but rather below by quite a few pixels.

If you could at least point me in the right direction, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: I think that this could be much easier, if you would throw jQuery into mix. Pure CSS solution would be pretty evil to do imo.

Comment: Ahh yes jQuery, sadly my knowledge of it is absolutely nothing. I suppose I may have some studying to do... I'd love to learn it because I've seen demos of all the amazing thing's you can do it with it. It looks quite involved though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is possible to replicate it, but not without some trickery.

You can see a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/u3n5c/

The essence to solving the problem is realizing that the :hover events will be triggered even if the parent container is smaller than its child. Visually, it seems that the line and the tab are separate elements, but in code they are the typical li > a.

Comment: I have a question though, is there any way to use background images for this method you're using?

Comment: Yes, you would have to replace the borders with images and account for the height of the borders. The tabs would be better with just the texture and applying the rounded borders and the shadow via css.

Comment: I've got all the textures setup and functioning nicely. One problem I can't seem to workaround though, is sending the tabs "to the back." Yes, I've tried playing with all the z-indexs to no avail. I want the bar's (ul element) box-shadow to fall "in front of" of the pull down tabs (li elements). - Thank you for you assistance once again!

Comment: My original fiddle cheats a little bit, instead of hiding the tabs behind the ul, it adjusts the height of the anchors, making it look like they hide behind but they are just resizing. If you put your code in jsfiddle I might be able to help you out.

Comment: Yes, I realized that relatively early on; which is why I was a bit stumped at first on the best way to use background images. Here is the link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YGPJb/19/.

Comment: Make it look like the shadow is falling on top through inset box shadows http://jsfiddle.net/kF8vG/

Comment: Simple solution, looks like it works well. Another issue that I ran into though using this technique is that, if I use any sort of image within the li tag, it will always sit over top of the shadow. It looks like I am going to have to make a compromise somewhere.

Comment: Use the image as a background-image of a, it will adjust to the border radius and the shadows will fall on top of it.

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried that and it does indeed go behind the inset shadow, however the image doesn't "move." when you hover, it just exposes more of the image. Let me try and upload a sample to my server...

Comment: You can see the working sample here: http://nside-elite.techiedesign.net/redbox/flashtest.html The first button (News) is the one that uses the background image on a. The other four buttons are the ones that contain img tags within the a.

Comment: Almost there! You need to specify the position of the background image, otherways it defaults to top left: background: url('mtl3.jpg') 50% 100% repeat; then adjust the source image so the text is at the bottom instead of the center.

Comment: And it does look quite similar to the original flash version, good job!

Comment: Thank you, however, I don't think I would have been able to complete this if it wasn't for your 'jumpstart' code. Thank you once again for all your assistance. You can see the final result implemented already at my site: http://nside-elite.techiedesign.net/drupal6.